# Automated Full export and Upload to FTP?

Tags: data-export

I want to create an automated process, that will trigger/create the Export Service

- https://eu1.salesforce.com/ui/setup/export/DataExportPage/d

[image]

And once complete, will upload all the resulting files to an FTP.

The files are 512MB in size each.

Is this supported in any way?

I thought of parsing the resulting page once I get the confirmation mail, but that seems so '90s'

Comment: Just wondering if this is one for Selenium?

Comment: The same question is over on stack overflow. Check out the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178279/how-to-automate-download-of-weekly-export-service-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apex Data Loader can be configured to run commandline.
You can schedule the Data Loader to run using the Windows Task Scheduler or a Cron job, write the csv files to a local directory.

Then write a simple Windows BAT file or Shell Script to pick up the csv files written to disk by the data loader process and FTP it to the remote FTP Server.

References :
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269

Additionally, DBAmp is a very popular (and powerful) Data Backup tool, which lets you replicate your salesforce data to a SQL database or similar.

Answer (score 4):

The FREE Jitterbit data loader lets you query all fields, export to an FTP site, and to schedule that process.

Only downside is spending an hour or two setting up the query for each object (custom and system).

On the plus side, it exports a lot of objects that the salesforce data export doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, you can try this solution to [upload data on FTP server using Command line dataloader.](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-dataloader-and-ant-to-backup-salesforce-data-on-ftp-server-video/)